# Real-valued function with strictly positive integral on every subinterval of [0, 1]

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, riemann-integration

Assume we have a Riemann-integrable function $h: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ such that

\begin{equation}
\int_a^b h(x)dx > 0\quad \forall a, b: 0 \leq a < b \leq 1.
\end{equation}

Further assume that $f, g: [0, 1] \to \mathbb R$ are continuous functions with

\begin{equation}
f(x) \geq g(x) \quad\forall x \in [0, 1].
\end{equation}

I suspect that in this case

> \begin{equation}
> \int_0^1 f(x)h(x)dx \geq \int_0^1 g(x)h(x)dx.
> \end{equation}

However, I cannot prove this (I need this as part of another proof). I would like to stay within "elementary" analysis, i.e., do not resort to measure theory (no "almost everywhere" stuff).

Many thanks.

Comment: The inequality does indeed hold, as your assumption implies that $h$ is positive almost everywhere. But I have no idea how to prove this using only elementary analysis. So far I have only two simplifications: You may assume $g \equiv 0$ and that $f$ is strictly greater than zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a proof that works even under weaker conditions. $f$ and $g$ need to be merely Riemann-integrable and $\int_a^b h(x) \, dx \ge 0$ needs to hold (i.e. the integral does not have to be strictly positive).

We can assume wlog $g \equiv 0$.

Let $Z_n$ be a sequence of meshes of $[0, 1]$ with $|Z_n| \to 0$. Since $h$ is Riemann-integrable, we know $\int_0^1 h(x) \, dx = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \overline{S}(Z_n, h)$, where $\overline{S}(Z, h) = \sum \limits_{I \in Z} |I| \sup \limits_{x \in I} h(x)$.

Since the integral of $h$ is nonnegative on every interval, we know that $\sup \limits_{x \in I} h(x) \ge 0$ holds for all (nondegenerate) intervals $I \subset [0, 1]$. But from this we can conclude that $\sup \limits_{x \in I} \{f(x) h(x)\} \ge 0$. Since $f \cdot h$ is Riemann-integrable, this yields the assertion:

$$\int f(x) h(x) \, dx = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \overline{S}(Z_n, f \cdot h) = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sum \limits_{I \in Z_n} |I| \sup \limits_{x \in I}\{ f(x) h(x)\}  \ge \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \sum \limits_{I \in Z_n} 0 = 0$$

Comment: How are you sure that $\sup \limits_{x \in I} h(x) \ge 0$ holds for all nondegenerate intervals in $[0,1]$?

Comment: I guess because of $|I|\sup \limits_{x \in I} h(x) \geq \int_I h(x) \geq 0$, where the second inequality holds by assumption.

Comment: @FedePoncio If $K := \sup \limits_{x \in I} h(x) < 0$ for some nondegenerate interval $I$, then $h(x) \le K/2$ on $I$ and by monotonicity of integrals we have $\int_I h(x) \, dx \le \int_I K/2 = |I| K/2 < 0$. But this is a contradiction to our assumption.

Comment: But, take for example $h(x)=x-1/4$, and $[0,0.2]$, there $|I|=0.2$ and $\sup \limits_{x \in [0,0.2]} h(x)=-0.05$, so $|I|\sup \limits_{x \in I} h(x) =(0.2)(-0.05)=-0.01\leq0$. Why does the integral being positive imply that $h(x)$ is nonnegative for every subinterval?

Comment: @FedePoncio The assumption is not just that $h$ has a positive integral, but that the integral over every subinterval is also positive (resp. nonnegative in my version).

Comment: @Dominik Oh!! Thank you, I was completely confused. Thanks

Comment: @FedePoncio I.e., my comment is right?

Comment: @chp Yes, your comment is correct.